# Want to mock a dependency that belongs to another class

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

What I want to test is abc() method from UserServiceImpl class. Within that method it invokes xyz(), which is belongs to UserDao dependency. In UserDao class it has a dependency of UserRepository and xyz() method uses it.
So how can I mock UserRepository dependency when I test abc() method? Really appreciate any kind of help.

```
    public class UserServiceImpl{

    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    public void abc(){
        userDao.xyz("a");
    }
    }
```

```
    public class UserDao{

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    public void xyz(String a){
        Optional<User> userOptional = userRepository.findByName("mike");
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test `UserServiceImpl.abc()` then mock `UserDao` and define a return value for `UserDao.xyz()` I see you have `void` method without parameter but for the example have `String` as param and return with a `User`.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes={UserServiceImpl.class})
public class UserServiceImplTest{

    @Autowired
    UserServiceImpl userSvc;

    @MockBean
    UserDao userDao;
    
    @Test
    public void abcTest(){
        //define User to return and the mock
        User userToReturn = new User("Mike");

        when(userDao.xyz("mike")).thenReturn(userToReturn);
        User retUser=userSvc.abc("mike");

        //do some assertion...

    }
}
```

If you want to test UserDao then do this in its own Test class.

Answer (score 1):

If you mock UserDao you don't need to mock UserRepository because only the real UserDao needs it.

And if you move your @Autowired annotation to the constructor it will be easier to inject in your test.

```
public class UserServiceImpl{


    private final UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImpl(UserDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    public void abc(){
        userDao.xyz("a");
    }

}
```

Test:

```
UserDao userDao = mock(UserDao.class);

UserServiceImpl subject = new UserServiceImpl(userDao);
subject.abc();
[...]
```